# update xml file with bash

Tags: bash, symfony, xliff

I make the internalization of a symfony2 site web, my code can generate unit translation like this:

```
 <trans-unit id="861b143b00e2f350dfe22876922294066b160351" resname="utilisez.ff.chrome">
    <source>utilisez.ff.chrome</source>
    <target state="new">utilisez.ff.chrome</target>
    <jms:reference-file line="85">Resources/views/base.html.twig</jms:reference-file>
    <jms:reference-file line="62">Resources/views/base_jq.html.twig</jms:reference-file>
  </trans-unit>
```

I have a csv file with data `source;target (utilisez.ff.chrome; utilisez de préférence Firefox ou Chrome)` I would like to make a bash file which replace the target value with the value in the file. If you can help me it will be very nice :) I have little skills on bash command. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [xmlstarlet](/questions/tagged/xmlstarlet) & [xpath](/questions/tagged/xpath) :

using the `@id` :

```
xmlstarlet edit -L \
-u "//trans-unit[@id="861b143b00e2f350dfe22876922294066b160351"]/target/text()"\
-v 'utilisez de préférence Firefox ou Chrome' file.xml
```

or using text of the csv :

```
src="$(cut -d';' -f2 file.csv | tr -d $'\n')"
rep="$(cut -d';' -f3 file.csv | tr -d $'\n')"
xmlstarlet edit -L -u "//target/text()[@text()='$src'" -v "$rep" file.xml
```

#### OUTPUT of edited *in place* file :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<trans-unit id="861b143b00e2f350dfe22876922294066b160351" resname="utilisez.ff.chrome">
  <source>utilisez.ff.chrome</source>
  <target state="new">utilisez de pr&#xE9;f&#xE9;rence Firefox ou Chrome</target>
  <jms:reference-file line="85">Resources/views/base.html.twig</jms:reference-file>
  <jms:reference-file line="62">Resources/views/base_jq.html.twig</jms:reference-file>
</trans-unit>
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, but i can not use this because i have many trans-unit tag in my xliff file

Comment: Just need to adapt the xpath